# RewriteRule to redirect at index.php: file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-7, apache2.2

I have installed apache2.2 with php70 using MacPorts on OSX El Captain.

I have next .htaccess in the folder v3:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I acess http://localhost/~user/v3/version it says `The requested URL /Users/user/Sites/v3/index.php was not found on this server`. I am sure that the file is there.

BTW, if I use http://localhost/~user/v3/index.php/version, everything is working fine.

Contents of `/opt/local/apache2/conf/users/user.conf`:

```
<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With previous version of php55, everything was working. What might cause this?

**EDIT:**

Apache error_log (it appears many times):

`[Fri Jun 24 12:52:36 2016] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/Users`

Instead of `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/Users` it should be `/Users`

**EDIT 2:**
I created a symbolic link `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/Users` pointing to `/Users`. Ugly fix but now I get in apache access_log:

`localhost - - [26/Jun/2016:12:29:04 -0300] "GET /~user/v3/version HTTP/1.1" 404 550`

Comment: So what is your `doc root` defined as in apache config? It seems you have set as `/Users/user/Sites/` I don't believe your pointing the URL to the correct location.

Comment: `DocumentRoot /opt/local/apache2/htdocs` which is a symbolic link to `/opt/local/www`. Anyway, php is working for my user (for example `http://localhost/~user/phpminiadmin.php`), just the redirection somehow doesn't.

Comment: I use `LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so` & `Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`.

Comment: You should include both of the rewrite conditions and I would also use a rewritebase. 
`RewriteBase /v3/`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: Tried that, but didn't help...

Comment: I used RewriteBase /~user/v3 and it started to work. Why it has the wrong base by default?

Comment: It doesn't look wrong by default. You have your project in 2 folders deep. It's the way you did your folder structure.  It looks like `http://localhost/` is your root. Your setup seems overly complicated. Mine is just `/var/www/sitename/html`. Done no symlinks or alias' if you set it up correctly.